# How can I open modal view (formsheet) from UITableView?

Tags: xcode, ipad, uitableview, modalviewcontroller

I am tired try open a modal view controller from ipad application.
How I can show a modal view like formsheet?

here my code block.
like this style opening a window (full screen) but there is don't have any object from my modal view

```
viewDetail *hd = [[viewDetail alloc] init];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:hd];

hd.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];

[hd release];
[nav release];
```

just i want open a formSheet modal view when selected a value from UITableView
by the way, i am development on xcode 4.2.1 and usind storyboard features
thanks for help.

like that give a SIGABRT error

```
viewDetail *hd = [[viewDetail alloc] initWithNibName:@"viewDetail" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:hd];

hd.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];

[hd release];
[nav release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my solution, worked a xib file out of story board.
But why wasn't it working in storyboard? There is a way for that?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using storyboards, you have to set `[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewDetail"];` as your `viewDetail` View Controller. (Assuming you set the Storyboard Identifier accordingly)

hope that helps.